# accounts[0] returns network name in string

Tags: ethereum, truffle, ganache

I am running a set of smart contracts in test mode in order to perform some initial tests. However and very strangely, when running `truffle migrate --network testrpc` and using `accounts[0]` in my migration files, I get the following error:
`Error: Provided address "t" is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be converted.`

In this string, "t" is in fact the first letter of testrpc. If I use accounts[1] I get a "e", etc...

I was previously using testrpc command line encironment and later switched to ganache-cli to try and solve the issue. Unfortunately nothing worked quite as I expected and I am still stuck with the issue.

I am running on Ubuntu so that may cause the issue?

EDIT 1: Migration file:

```
// Starting deployment of asset
module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {

    // owner wallet
    var wallet = accounts[0];

};
```

Comment: Can you show the migration file?

Comment: In essence it is the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find why it didn't work with `testrpc`, so I switched to `ganache-cli` which also provided the same issue... I finally resigned myself to use Ganache Client app, and it worked...